# lightning bolt issue raspberry pi 4

Tags: hardware, raspberry-pi-os

I'm using raspberry pi 4 model B, unfortunately, I got a lightning bolt at the right corner

I searched online about this issue and I found a lot of topics that explain the issue

I tried to replace my power supply, and I used the official power supply that came with the raspberry pi

I still getting the lightning bolt + low voltage warning

but when I searched, I found that people with this problem can use their mouse and keyboard normally, but in my case, I can't use them

when I tried to use my touch screen, it didn't work neither

So, what is exactly the problem? I tried everything even installing new software but it didn't work

important note: the raspberry pi became really hot once I start it with any power supply (including the one that came with it).

Comment: What is connected to your Pi when you get the lightning bolt? Have you tried disconnecting everything other than the monitor?

Comment: According to the "official documentation": The "lightning bolt" is used as an icon by the system to communicate ["low voltage"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/README.md#troubleshoot-power). Your question implies that you may have initially used something other than an official supply? Given the overheating, perhaps try to get a refund/return from your vendor.

Comment: The lightning bolt points out an power issue. If you use the official power supply you shouldn't get the lightling bolt. But I noticed you wrote "when I tried to use my touch screen, it didn't work neither" which sounds to me you attached additional equipment to your Raspberry which also needs power. Unplug every additional HW  to check whether you still have an issue.

Comment: undervoltage..  your pi and connected devices are overwhelming the power.

If you've overclocked and configured over voltage this will also add to the problem.

A powered USB hub can help with power drain from USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

try plugging into an [UPC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HDC236Q).

your wall-plug is probably not grounded properly.

Comment: The official Raspberry Pi power supply is double insulated so does not need any connection to mains ground. The lightning bolt is due to a power supply that doesn't meet the power requirements of the Raspberry Pi it's connected to.